# How do I delete all css classes except one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby

I have a string:

```
html = 'class="repository-content frozen interface">'
```

CSS rules `repository-content` can be located anywhere:

```
html = 'class="frozen repository-content interface">'
```

Help me create a regular expression to delete all classes except `repository-content`

my version:

```
html.gsub(/[^\s?forbidden-word\s?]/, '')
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: Why not `html = 'class="repository-content"'`?

Comment: Why do you need to handle and manipulate HTML as strings in the frist place? What is the use case?

Comment: This is rather unclear. Do you mean you need to match `class="`, any chars but `"`, `"` and then just keep `class="repository-content"`? Use `html.sub(/class="[^"]*"/, 'class="repository-content"')`. See https://ideone.com/8HhEJB

Comment: Try `nokogiri`. `doc.css('span[class~="repository-content"]')` will get you all the elements with class containing `repository-content`. Then, just set them to `repository-content`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew is spot on with Nokogiri. Manipulating HTML with regular expressions is a fools errand.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if there is a `repository-content` you only need to leave it, if there are any other css classes, you need to remove them.

Comment: The logic I shared is exactly that (with nokogiri).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better to think this the other way around (basically whitelisting instead of blacklisting). If you *know* the word you want to keep you can do this:

```
irb(main):001:0> html = 'class="frozen repository-content-2 repository-content interface">'
=> "class=\"frozen repository-content-2 repository-content interface\">"

irb(main):002:0> html.gsub(/class=".*?(repository-content(?=[\s"])).*?"/, 'class="\1"')
=> "class=\"repository-content\">"
irb(main):003:0>
```

So the idea here is to keep the word you want and remove surrounding (forbidden) words.

```
.*?  this is to match 0 or more characters (non-greedy)

\1   is to keep the word you want inside the class="..."
```

Comment: If there is a class with a similar name, for example, `repository-content-2`, then `-2` removed. And stays `repository-content`. But in this case you also need to remove the css class `repository-content-2`. Can you tell me how to make a more accurate regular expression?

Comment: `"class="repository-content-2">"` - this is a different css rules, so it should returned `"class="">"` or `""`

Comment: We could also suggest regexp for `2-repository-content` ?